# How to refresh list View in android?

Tags: android, android-listview, refresh

I am using .net web services. I am trying to get list in `ListView`. Right now it is showing me the first list, but when I am trying to get it again using the same method it is giving me a response in log but not displaying in list.

I have used `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` in my `Adapter` but it's not working. Please help. thanks

My code:

```
Intent mIntent = getIntent();
    mIntent.getStringExtra("folder_name");
    Id = mIntent.getStringExtra("folder_ID");
    mIntent.getStringExtra("item_parent");
    User_ID = mIntent.getStringExtra("User_ID");

    subfolderTreedata();   
}
    public void subfolderTreedata() {
    try {
  --------
  --------
  --------  //some code here...

 SoapObject SubfolderResponse = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();

        Log.i("SubFolders", SubfolderResponse.toString());

        String File_Ext=" ";

        subfoldersitem = new String[SubfolderResponse.getPropertyCount()];

        System.out.println(subfoldersitem.length);

        for(int i=0; i < SubfolderResponse.getPropertyCount(); i++) {
            SoapObject SingleSubFolder = (SoapObject)SubfolderResponse.getProperty(i);

            subfoldersitem[0] = SingleSubFolder.getProperty(1).toString();
            subfoldersitem[1] = SingleSubFolder.getProperty(0).toString();
            subfoldersitem[2] = SingleSubFolder.getProperty(3).toString();

            if(KEY_SUBJECTTYPE.equalsIgnoreCase("Folder")) {

            item = new FolderList(Folderimages[0], subfoldersitem[0], subfoldersitem[1], subfoldersitem[2]);
            Subfolderdata.add(item);

            } else{

                StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(Name, ".");
                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                String first_string = tokens.nextToken();
                File_Ext = tokens.nextToken();

                    if(File_Ext.equalsIgnoreCase("TIF")) {
                        item = new FolderList(TIFimages[0], subfoldersitem[0], subfoldersitem[1], subfoldersitem[2]);
                        Subfolderdata.add(item);

                    } else {
                        item = new FolderList(noImage[0], subfoldersitem[0], subfoldersitem[1], subfoldersitem[2]);
                        Subfolderdata.add(item);  }
        }
    }
            subfolderslistview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.subfolderslistview);

            mAdapter = new LazyAdapter(this, R.layout.jpg_row, Subfolderdata);
            subfolderslistview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            subfolderslistview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                    LazyAdapter ca = (LazyAdapter)parent.getAdapter();
                    FolderList item_name = (FolderList)ca.getItem(position);
                    FolderList DocumentID = (FolderList)ca.getItem(position);
                    FolderList type = (FolderList)ca.getItem(position);

                    Intent mIntent = new Intent();  
                    mIntent.putExtra("item_name", item_name.folder_name);
                    mIntent.putExtra("item_id", DocumentID.ID);
                    mIntent.putExtra("item_type", type.type);

                    mIntent.getStringExtra("item_name");

                    String Type = mIntent.getStringExtra("item_type");

                    Log.i("Type", Type);

                    if(Type.equalsIgnoreCase("Folder")){

                        Id = mIntent.getStringExtra("item_id");
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        subfolderTreedata();

                    } else {

                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Display_image.class);
                        i.putExtra("item_name", item_name.folder_name);
                        i.putExtra("ID", DocumentID.ID);
                        i.putExtra("item_type", type.type);
                        i.putExtra("User_ID",User_ID);

                        i.getStringExtra("item_name");
                        Id = i.getStringExtra("ID");
                        i.getStringExtra("item_type");
                        Log.i("id", Id);
                        startActivity(i);
                        }
                     }
                 });
```

Comment: Is the code you used, `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` not sufficient?

Comment: @shiva hey , m also in chandigarh , enter in this room, let us chat at here , chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24164/discussion-between-rohit-and-tushar

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24164/discussion-between-rohit-and-tushar

Comment: No, it is not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void list() {
    mAdapter = new LazyAdapter(this, R.layout.jpg_row, Subfolderdata);
    subfolderslistview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Use like this `list();`.

Call this method from Where do you want.

Comment: Don't use notifyDataSetChanged(); This one won't work at some condition.

Comment: Hey nirmal, I have resolved the issue. And But the only issue is when I am returning back it is showing first folder list not returning step wise...